# How to add a Button in the SpreadsheetView table

Tags: java, controlsfx

How can I create a object(Button,Checkbox) in my table?

```
    GridBase grid = new GridBase(20, 20);

    ObservableList<ObservableList<SpreadsheetCell>> rows = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for (int row = 0; row < grid.getRowCount(); ++row) {
        final ObservableList<SpreadsheetCell> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int column = 0; column < grid.getColumnCount(); ++column) {
            list.add(new ObjectType().createCell(row, column, 1, 1, new Button("CLICK")));
        }
        rows.add(list);
    }
    grid.setRows(rows);
    SpreadsheetView spv = new SpreadsheetView(grid);
```

Output in the table:

Button@79280814[styleClass=button]'CLICK'

Button@3ad2325d[styleClass=button]'CLICK'

Answer (score 1):

I think i have found it :)

1-)

```
 SpreadsheetCellBase cell = new SpreadsheetCellBase(row, column, 1, 1);

                        cell.setGraphic(new Button("Test Button"));

                        list.add(cell)
```

---

2-)

```
SpreadsheetCell cellIndex = SpreadsheetCellType.STRING.createCell(row, column, 1, 1,null); 

                    cellIndex.setGraphic(new Button("Test Button"));

                    cells.add(cellIndex);
```

Comment: You are right. The objectType you used is using the toString method in order to display the object.

So you have to either create your own Type, or just use a StringType like you did and set the graphic.